# Why not use the CiviCRM emblem/icon?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I notice this SE has a generic "comment bubble" icon with "cc" in it. What's that stand for? Closed Captioning? [joke]

I think this baby would look sweet as the icon for this StackExchange:

[image: CiviCRM emblem/logo]

Why not use it?

Comment: I gotta say, the moment I saw the meta favicon here, I thought of closed captioning, too.

Comment: Looks like we got a nice compromise— a stylized Civi icon in the Beta colors. Yay StackExchange team— especially as no one would have recognized CC as referring to CiviCRM.

Comment: Very nice! Easy to spot it among the sea of open tabs ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All StackExchange sites in Beta use [a standard theme](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/the-new-stack-exchange-beta-theme-2/). If you explore the [newest sites in the network](http://stackexchange.com/sites#newest), you'll notice that the beta sites all use this theme, with the exception of the language-specific branches of StackOverflow.

This helps distinguish the beta sites, those whose scopes are being adjusted and whose cultures are being formed, from the larger and more-established stacks. It also saves StackExchange from expending resources on customization on sites for which it is unclear when, or even if, graduation will come. When that day does come, the designers will [go to town](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/10/ask-ubuntu-stack-exchange-site-out-of-beta-new-awesome-domain).

Comment: Neat, thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

The quickest and easiest answer to your question is "that's CiviCRM's logo; they own it, we don't." And choster is generally right; most of our new/beta sites use the same generic theme.

There are exceptions, though. I don't remember the details offhand, but [Craft CMS Stack Exchange](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com) has an icon that's sort of a hybrid of our rectangular speech bubble thing and [Craft's](https://buildwithcraft.com/) distinctive letter C and shade of red. If CiviCRM would be interested in doing something similar, we could definitely look into this more closely.

**Update:**
Thanks to the support and logo-generosity of the CiviCRM team, this is now implemented!

Comment: the core team and CiviCRM LLC are fully in support of this site, and would be happy to discuss use of our logo with you.

Comment: @Coleman cool, send me an e-mail (pops@stackexchange)!